# CDC Data Only Shows up After 5 Minutes

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I've set up CDC on my database and can see records inserted into the _CT and `lsn_time_mapping` table. However, when I use the following query to get the change data immediately after the change I don't see any results:

```
SELECT  ct.Id,
        sys.fn_cdc_map_lsn_to_time(__$start_lsn) TransactionDateTime
FROM    cdc.dbo_myTable_CT ct
WHERE   Id = 40
AND     __$start_lsn >= sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn('smallest greater than', '3/1/2015') 
AND     __$start_lsn < sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn('largest less than', '5/1/2015')
Group By __$start_lsn, ct.Id
```

After 5 minutes, the same query will return my change data.

I've also noticed that a row like this gets inserted into `lsn_time_mapping` every 5 minutes:

```
start_lsn               tran_begin_time         tran_end_time           tran_id tran_begin_lsn

0x0000048E0000004A0001  2015-04-06 11:32:19.840 2015-04-06 11:32:19.840 0x00    0x00000000000000000000
```

It appears that until such a record is inserted after the change I won't get my change from the above query.

Can anyone explain what's going on here?

Comment: Because the capture process extracts change data from the transaction log, there is a built in latency between the time that a change is committed to a source table and the time that the change appears within its associated change table. While this latency is typically small, it is nevertheless important to remember that change data is not available until the capture process has processed the related log entries.

[link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645937(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: @RazzleDazzleThanks for the explanation. Do you know what could cause the latency to be so big? 5 minutes of latency seems pretty bad. And I wonder why it's always 5 minutes.